# Heroku-deployed Django webpage doesn't update when DB changes

Tags: python, node.js, django, heroku, sqlite

I have deployed an app in Heroku using Django. The Django program uses a SQLite database `db.sqlite3` on root directory to populate its page. Separately, there is also a Node.js scraper program that inserts to that database.

The problem is that the hard-refreshed webpage shows the same data even after the content of the database changed. Curiously, this does not happen when it is tested locally with `python manage.py runserver`. How can I fix this problem?

Thank you in advance!

---

For reference, here is my requirements.txt file:

```
Django==1.10.6  
gunicorn==19.7.1
Pillow==4.0.0
selenium==3.3.1
whitenoise==3.3.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **cannot** use sqlite on Heroku.

An sqlite db is stored as a file on the local filesystem. But in Heroku the filesystem is ephemeral and is not shared between dynos. Every time you redeploy your app, or scale your process, or in your case launch a worker, you get a new filesystem with a *different* copy of the db file.

Use the proper Postgres support via the add-ons.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I did read in multiple Heroku docs about discouraging sqlite due to ephemeral filesystem, but I did not think that could be the cause of the problem. I'll try using the Heorku Postgres addon!